# Restrict SSH users to SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp, account-restrictions

How to configure an SSH server to only allow users to transfer files using the SFTP protocol, without being able to log in with their username ?

Note: If the user's shell to nologin or null is not possible to change this

Comment: I don't understand your note. Your sentence isn't grammatically correct and I don't understand what you're trying to say. Are the users' shell set to `nologin` or not? Why wouldn't you change this, since it's the way to do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
Find the line something like `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`.
Next you have two options (should work both, I do not remember which one I have used).  First, you may register this executable as a shell and set it for the user, or, the second one, ForcedCommand for that user in sshd_config.